# cannot login to mysql server in xampp

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have installed XAMPP on windows 10. Apache server is working fine, but when I try to go to 'localhost/phpmyadmin' I get the error : Cannot log in to the MySQL server / Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

I am already using wamp local server on the same machine but I have changed the port number for apache and mysql in xampp.

Here is my config.inc.php file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg'Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
```

I have also tried commenting out "controluser" and "controlpass" but still could not resolve the issue.

Comment: does it work for 'host' set to localhost. MySQL permissions us text matching for the connection source so 127.0.0.1 and localhost are not the same

Comment: update this to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried changing 127.0.0.1 to localhost, still no luck. I ain't got a clue what am I missing to get through.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the below settings and remove the mysql password if it is set already.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
```

And do not set any password for controlpass. Let it be blank. Then restart you apache.

Comment: When I uncomment the 'controluser' and 'controlpass' I get the error: Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.